# What is the easiest way to send a file or a text message from a server to a client if SSH is not an option?

Tags: linux, file-transfer, messaging

What is the easiest way to send a file or a text message securely from a server to a client if SSH is not an option?

Hello,

I am working on a cloud server and I want to send a small file or text message securely (important) from the server to a client. Ideally I want to receive the file or message directly in the client Terminal. There is no X so everything has to be through command line.

SSH is not an option, too many Firewalls and stuff.

Syncthing is too complicated to use from command line (have to use the REST API, no flags or commands available).

Talk does not seem to work for this purpose.

E-mail is probably not secure enough.

Tmate cannot do this as far as I know and it's not persistent over sessions.

Vesa

Edit: Please note, there is no X so everything has to be through command line. Also the solution should be scriptable without need for manual intervention.

Comment: What do you mean by "securely"? Do you just want to be sure that the message arrives? Or that it arrives unchanged? Or that no one else can read it? Can you share a separate secret (password) between the server & client?

Comment: Well, granted, the message should arrive, otherwise there would not be any point in sending it. It should also be impossible to read for others and yes, unchanged as well. The server and client can be preconfigured to store passwords.

Comment: "Easiest" is very much a function of "what tools do you have available, and how is the whole system set up". "Too many firewalls" indicate complications we know nothing about.

Comment: @dirkt The server is running Ubuntu, very recent version and I can access most tools there are. So there are probably some good solutions for this issue. With regard to the firewalls I have tested SSH and ruled it out because I don't want to run an SSH server either on the sending computer or the receiving computer.

Comment: If the problem isn't that ssh can't get through the firewalls: You'll have to run some sort of "server" anyway, no matter if you "type" the server on your commandline using available tools, or if you just start it. Setting up an ssh-server is trivial, secure, and solves all the problems you'd need to solve manually. If you insist on doing it manually, first thing that comes to mind is socat/netcat (which will start a temporary "server") on both the receiving and teh sending computer. You'll have to encrypt and decrypt yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Answering the original "What is the easiest way to send a file or a text message *securely* from a server to a client if SSH is not an option?":

If by "securely" you mean that no one else can read it, then I think the easiest answer is to just use [GPG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Privacy_Guard) and encrypt the file.

Either by using a (secret) shared passphrase and gpg's `-c, --symmetric` option, or  create a keypair at both ends, share the public keys, and create messages back & forth through any private or public means available, plain email, telnet, a public webpage, usenet, anything that can send a file.

---

With the question edited to remove the *secure* requirement, the easiest is probably to just send an email.

However, with edits constantly moving the goalpost (not secure, no GUI, command line only, then no manual intervention) I'm not sure what the root question is anymore. So just use ssh, or ftp, or netcat, or telnet, but they all need servers set up & ports opened in firewalls, etc. Or wget, or lynx with a 3rd server somewhere.

Comment: Wait, it's the last part I need help with. I don't need a lot of help encrypting with GPG. As I said, I have already ruled out e-mail and SSH. I would ideally want to receive the file or text message directly in my Terminal on the client side. I have considered Telnet but I'm not sure about how to configure it. I would prefer not having to set up servers on either side of the network.

Comment: Why not just send an email? If you've got *"too many Firewalls and stuff"* preventing ssh, I'm not sure if telnet would be very different. Or an IM program that sends files, like pidgin, empathy, gajim, kopete, etc

Comment: This is command line only. I have tested a lot of email clients and servers for Terminal over the years but never found anything that feels like the right tool for the job. There might be some package and some way to configure it to make it suitable but I have never found it yet over the course of the years. Actually i have been thinking about this issue for a while, there should be some dead easy and smooth way to send a message from one Terminal to another over the Internet. If you know an efficient way, please let me know.

Comment: That wasn't a hard requirement of the question originally (honestly it's still a rather vague question, I was only going to comment originally but technically I seemed to have "an answer"...) but anyway ssh sounds best, or ftp/sftp, or telnet, but they all need servers set up & ports opened in firewalls, etc. Or there's `wget` to download a file from a web server, or even the terminal web browser `lynx` could sign into web email with (gmail might not work, but they're not the only email game in town, there still should be cheap/free shell accounts with email around somewhere)